# Cluster analysis with conjoint analysis data

Tags: self-study, clustering

My team and I need to do a conjoint analysis for our school project with SPSS. We were able to get the utility to each level of our attributes by doing a survey using 16 cards generated with the orthogonal design.

However, we also have to do a cluster analysis. What is confusing us is how to use our data to generate the cluster analysis and the chi-square test. I have been looking online for a while, but all the cluster analysis that I was able to find had data that did not look like our data at all. For example, they had a single column "color" with multiple values below... Our data, after the conjoint analysis, is more like 3 columns: color1, color2, color3 (based on our orthogonal design).

I tried to run a K-Means Cluster Analysis with a K of 2 and I was able to find two "packages" based on my attributes, however, since I had 3 rows for my "color", is it okay to interpret it as "the highest of the 3 takes the spot in the cluster"? For example:

```
Cluster     1      2
-------------------------
Color1      3      -0.2
Color2      -1.3   3
Color3      1.1    1.2
Weight1     1      -0.1
Weight2     0.2    1.3
Weight3     3      0.2
```

Would give me Color1, Weight3 for Cluster 1 and Color2, Weight2 for Cluster 2.

Otherwise, we also have the data file which has all of our cards with a number between 0 and 100 associated with them for each respondent, but I do not see how we could make a useful cluster analysis out of those...

Comment: Add the self-study tag.

Comment: Self-study tag added.